# SQL Server Grouping

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables as follow:

```
DECLARE @Orders table ( OrderId int NOT NULL,
                        CustomerId int NOT NULL,
                        OrderDate datetime NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY ( OrderId ) );

    DECLARE @Printers table ( PrinterId int NOT NULL,
                          Printer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                          Size varchar(6) NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY ( PrinterId ) );

    DECLARE @OrderBillPrints table ( OrderId int NOT NULL,
                                 PrinterId int NOT NULL,
                                 PrintDate datetime NOT NULL,
                                 PRIMARY KEY ( OrderId, PrinterId, PrintDate )       );`
```

and sample data:

```
 INSERT INTO @Orders ( OrderId, CustomerId, OrderDate )
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '20150105' ),
       ( 2, 5, '20150102' ),
       ( 3, 1, '20150110' ),
       ( 4, 3, '20150101' ),
       ( 5, 8, '20150215' ),
       ( 6, 5, '20150305' ),
       ( 7, 2, '20150228' ),
       ( 8, 1, '20150302' ),
       ( 9, 6, '20150301' )

   INSERT INTO @Printers ( PrinterId, Printer, Size )
   VALUES ( 1, 'Wild Bills Inkshop', 'Large' ),
       ( 2, 'Sammies Samples', 'Medium' ),
       ( 3, 'Large Font Press', 'Large' ),
       ( 4, '5_NE_HP_1400', 'Small' )

    INSERT INTO @OrderBillPrints ( OrderId, PrinterId, PrintDate )
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '20150101' ),
       ( 4, 3, '20150102' ),
       ( 2, 4, '20150102' ),
       ( 1, 1, '20150102' ),
       ( 5, 3, '20150102' ),
       ( 1, 3, '20150103' ),
       ( 1, 2, '20150103' ),
       ( 4, 2, '20150104' ),
       ( 3, 1, '20150112' ),
       ( 7, 4, '20150301' ),
       ( 9, 4, '20150301' ),
       ( 7, 4, '20150302' ),
       ( 7, 1, '20150302' ),
       ( 9, 2, '20150303' ),
       ( 9, 4, '20150303' ),
       ( 9, 2, '20150304' )
```

I need to query to see the most recent print run information for each order and I except a single record returned for each order with the following information:

> OrderId
>         OrderDate
>         LargestPrinterFromLastRun
>         LastPrintRunDate
>         LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize

The following is my query:

```
SELECT T.OrderId , MAX(T.LargestPrinterFromLastRun),  T.OrderDate ,
    MAX(T.LastPrintRunDate) as LastPrintRunDate, 
   MIN(LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize) AS 
   LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize FROM
  (
  SELECT 
  O.OrderId, MAX(o.OrderDate) AS OrderDate, 
  CASE 
    WHEN P.Printer IS NULL THEN '*N/A*'
    ELSE P.Printer
    END AS LargestPrinterFromLastRun, OBP.PrintDate AS LastPrintRunDate, 
    P.Size AS LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize 
   FROM @Orders O
    LEFT JOIN @OrderBillPrints OBP ON O.OrderId = OBP.OrderId
   LEFT JOIN @Printers P ON P.PrinterId = OBP.PrinterId
   GROUP BY O.OrderId, P.Size, P.Printer, OBP.PrintDate) T 
   GROUP BY T.OrderId, T.OrderDate

   ORDER BY T.OrderId ASC
```

The output should be:

```
OrderId OrderDate               LargestPrinterFromLastRun   LastPrintRunDate        LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize
1       2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 Large Font Press            2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 Large
2       2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 5_NE_HP_1400                2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Small
3       2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 Wild Bills Inkshop          2015-01-12 00:00:00.000 Large
4       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 Sammies Samples             2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 Medium
5       2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 Large Font Press            2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Large
6       2015-03-05 00:00:00.000 *N/A*                       NULL                    NULL
7       2015-02-28 00:00:00.000 Wild Bills Inkshop          2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 Large
8       2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 *N/A*                       NULL                    NULL
9       2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 Sammies Samples             2015-03-04 00:00:00.000 Medium
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my result which does not match

```
 OrderId        LargestPrinterFromLastRun   OrderDate               LastPrintRunDate        LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize
1           Wild Bills Inkshop          2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 Large
2           5_NE_HP_1400                2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Small
3           Wild Bills Inkshop          2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 2015-01-12 00:00:00.000 Large
4           Sammies Samples             2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 Large
5           Large Font Press            2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Large
6           *N/A*                       2015-03-05 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
7           Wild Bills Inkshop          2015-02-28 00:00:00.000 2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 Large
8           *N/A*                       2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
9           Sammies Samples             2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-04 00:00:00.000 Medium
```

Comment: Search for ranking functions like row_number() and Rank()

Comment: Assuming you are on 2012 or above look at the first_value function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx or http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/09/sql-server-introduction-to-first-_value-and-last_value-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/ I believe your OVER clause would ORDER BY the OrderDate.

Comment: Here is my result which does not match

Comment: 1 Wild Bills Inkshop 2015-01-05 00:00:00.000 2015-01-03 00:00:00.000 Large
2 5_NE_HP_1400 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Small
3 Wild Bills Inkshop 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 2015-01-12 00:00:00.000 Large
4 Sammies Samples 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 Large
5 Large Font Press 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 Large
6 *N/A* 2015-03-05 00:00:00.000 NULL NULL
7 Wild Bills Inkshop 2015-02-28 00:00:00.000 2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 Large
8 *N/A* 2015-03-02 00:00:00.000 NULL NULL
9 Sammies Samples 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-04 00:00:00.000 Medium

Comment: Are you sure you mean except?

Comment: How does MAX(T.LargestPrinterFromLastRun) or MIN have any meaning?  That is just an alphabetical sort.  Ditto for MIN(LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize).  And those two are not even directly associated with each other - they are independent Min Max.

Comment: I am sorry. I need to see the most recent print run information for each order. on the same day I want to see the largest printer. each record should has the following info:      OrderId 
 OrderDate
 LargestPrinterFromLastRun 
 LastPrintRunDate  
 LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize

Comment: This is what I came up with to match what the output should

Comment: And just how do you think that data represents largest?  An alphabetical sort on Printer or Size has no meaning relative to largest.   If that is a made up data design then this is not a specific programming problem.  The problem is way more than group by.  Sorry voting to close.  Break it down to a specific problem and build from there.

Comment: There is a column called size which golds three types: Large, Medium, and Small in @Printers table. When I do join, It should show what is the biggest size on that day.

Comment: I have a reporting need to see the most recent print run information for each order. I expect a single record returned for each order with the following information:
 OrderId 
 OrderDate
 LargestPrinterFromLastRun 
 LastPrintRunDate  
 LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize

Comment: Some orders can be very large and be submitted to multiple printers, or be printed over the course of multiple print runs.

Comment: Because multiple printers could handle different print runs on the same day I want to see the largest printer in those instances.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which matches with your results while using Rank()

```
SELECT OrderId,
       OrderDate,
       ISNULL(Printer,'*N/A* ') AS LargestPrinterFromLastRun,
       PrintDate AS LastPrintRunDate,
       SIZE AS LargestPrinterFromLastRunSize
FROM
  (SELECT A.OrderId,Printer, PrintDate ,SIZE,
     (SELECT max(OrderDate)
      FROM @Orders
      WHERE OrderDate =A.OrderDate) AS [OrderDate],
      RANK () OVER(PARTITION BY A.OrderId ORDER BY PrintDate DESC ,Printer ASC) Ranks
   FROM @Orders A
   LEFT JOIN @OrderBillPrints B ON A.OrderId=B.OrderId
   LEFT JOIN @Printers C ON B.PrinterId=C.PrinterId) Ms
WHERE Ranks=1
GROUP BY OrderId,
         [OrderDate],
         Printer,
         PrintDate,
         SIZE
```